# Is it possible to have multiple hasMany relationships using the same model?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a situation where I have a model meant to store several lists of chemicals. The chemical model is the same for each of the `hasMany` relationships.

I need something like this:

```
Ext.define('HandSurvey.model.ChemicalRisks', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'],
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        identifier: 'uuid',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'auto' }
        ],
        associations: [
            {
                type: 'hasMany',
                model : 'HandSurvey.model.SpecificChemical',
                name  : 'fiberglassResins',
                store : {
                    type: 'sql'
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'hasMany',
                model : 'HandSurvey.model.SpecificChemical',
                name  : 'paintsStains',
                store : {
                    type: 'sql'
                }
            },
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'sql'
        }
    }
});
```

But this would cause each list to bind to every `SpecificChemical` that belongs to the `ChemicalRisks` model, not just the ones meant to belong to that `hasMany`. It seems as though I would need to join on multiple fields

Is it possible to do this? Or do I have to make a bunch of the exact same models/stores with different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sure you can!**

**use associationKey and the autogenerated stores of the associations**

```
associations: [
            {
                type: 'hasMany',
                model : 'HandSurvey.model.SpecificChemical',
                name  : 'fiberglassResins',
                associationKey : 'fiberglassResins'
            },
            {
                type: 'hasMany',
                model : 'HandSurvey.model.SpecificChemical',
                name  : 'paintsStains',
                associationKey : 'paintsStains'
            },
        ]
```

Given a response like this: {

```
    "response" : {
        "fiberglassResins": [
            {
                "id"   : 1
                "name" : "Polyester"

            },
            {
                "id"   : 2
                "name" : "E-Glass"
            }

        ],
        "paintsStains": [
            {
                "id"   : 1
                "name" : "item1"

            },
            {
                "id"   : 2
                "name" : "item2"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

**Then you bind your main model to a store lets say ItemsStore.
IMPORTANT each record of ItemsStore will get autogenerated by Sencha: fiberglassResinsStore and paintsStainsStore.**

*Yo can console.log() each record to see the actual stores.*